# FastAPI schema from an OpenAPI yaml file

Tags: python, openapi, fastapi

I'm looking for a way to initialize a [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) server, with an existing OpenAPI YAML schema file.

The [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/) do describe how to modify the auto-generated schema, but I'm looking for something like [Connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which can generate the validators on-the-fly.

- a related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401878/how-to-extend-fastapi-docs-with-another-swagger-docs)
- a tool to generate a FastAPI project from an OpenAPI schema file can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-code-generator/), but did not work in my case (the project is still experimental)

**Edit**

I've traced down the offending property to this one:

```
class MyParameters(BaseModel):
    ...
    ModelName: Optional[ModelName] = Field(None, description='')
    ...
```

The matching object schema in openapi.yaml:

```
MyParameters:
    type: object
    properties:
        ...
        ModelName:
            type: string
            enum: [XYZ]
            description: ""
        ...
```

`ModelName` is not mandatory.

Comment: I was going to suggest the `fastapi-code-generator` but seems like it didn't work. Why?

Comment: Got an exception: TypeError: Optional[t] requires a single type. Got FieldInfo(description='', extra={})

Comment: The exception might be caused by syntax errors in your OpenAPI YAML file. Paste it into https://editor.swagger.io and if it reports any errors, fix them before using the generator.

Comment: @Helen tried it - schema is OK

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci I've traced the error to fastapi-code-generator's handing of enums: when encountering an enum in the schema file, it created an enum class, *with the same name as the property itself*. Subsequently, the creation of `Optional` fails typing._type_check(), which instead of receiving an Enum class, received a `FieldInfo`

Answer (score 3):

After resolving the issue with [fastapi-code-generator](https://github.com/koxudaxi/fastapi-code-generator), I've opted to use it.

For future readers, who use **Python 3.7**, the issue was a missing import in the generated `models.py` file:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Adding it at the top of `models.py` resolved the issue.